# Quote marks in controls' property in ASP.NET markup

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, markup, quotes

Sounds dummy but I can't set to a server-side control's property a value contains quote marks `"`:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ErrorMessage="Currency-from can't be equal to currency-to" runat="server"  />
```

I need to quote "from" and "to".

I tried escaping `\"from\"` and double quote marks `""from""` - both doesn't work. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes won't work because you also have a single quote on the text

Answer (score 4):

You could just use single quotes.

Or replace the double quotes with `"&quot ;"` (without the space between the t and semi-colon)

Comment: Single quote using like `ErrorMessage="Currency "from" can't be.."` doesn't work

Comment: I mean't like `ErrorMessage="Currency 'from' can't be.."` - but I would just use `&quot;` as everyone has suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `&quot;` for quotes, [this is how you escape them in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp), like this:

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Currency &quot;from&quot; can't be equal to currency &quot;to&quot;" />
```

(Also, fix the first spelling or Currency!)